# How to pass DOM element to a API function?

Tags: javascript, dom

While trying to integrate Yahoo Media Player into my own website, I want to allow users to click on a link to add the clicked track to the playlist. YMP API has got a function for doing that (http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/api/#method_addTracks). It takes a DOM element. Now how should I pass the dom element. My code looks like this right now:
...

```
<li id="track1">
<a href="location of track" style="display:none">track1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?, null, true);">Add this to the playlist</a>
</li>
```

if anyone has worked with YMP or has any idea about this please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand from the API page, you should be using

```
YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(document.getElementById('track1'), null, true);
```

(the documentation says "HTML DOM element (possibly **contains** media anchor tags)")

Comment: Yeah that was true. I finally figure that out (hit and trial). Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should place a reference to the DOM element you want to add, most likely by id like so:

```
<li id="track1">
<a id="trackelement" href="location of track" style="display:none">track1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(document.getElementById('trackelement'), null, true);">Add this to the playlist</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried that too but for some reasons it's not working. Is document.getElementByID() browser specific. I tried to see the output with alert(document.getElementByID('trackelement')) but nothing returns

Comment: Java script is case sensitive so use getElementById instead of getElementByID

Comment: And did you catch that Aron's example had the id attribute for the anchor tag?

Comment: sorry for the capital case. Yes, I caught id attribute but I don't have any luck still.

Comment: Any js errors appear or something? Try to execute this script in console (Firebug)

Answer (score 0):

i finally solved this.
this is what i did

```
<div id="debug"><a href="http://www.radioreloaded.com/audio/7k/6724_Akela Hoon Main.mp3">Akela hoon Mein, Raeth</a></div>

<a href="#" onclick="YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(document.getElementById("debug"),null,true);">Add to playlist</a>
```

to start playing the track you can

```
YAHOO.MediaPlayer.play();
```